# How can I add a continuous grayscale to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a grayscale color ramp to a continuous color scale in a ggplot for the variable z. A sample is below but I haven't been able to figure out how to make a continuous gray scale.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(0,10,1)
y <- seq(11,20,1)
z <- seq(21,30,1)

df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))

ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point(aes(color = z), size = 3)+
  scale_color_continuous(type = "viridis")
```

Comment: Dear ZT_Geo, I have provided an answer. If its sufficient for you please upvote the answer and accept the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of easily changing the color to a scale of grays is using `scale_color_distiller`. Just substitute `scale_color_continuous` in your script for the following line.

```
scale_color_distiller(type = "seq",
                        direction = -1,
                        palette = "Greys")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Actually thats a pretty neat option; Thanks for posting it

Comment: Great, this works perfectly! I would upvote but just started my account today and my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 2):

```
# First you set the border of the grey colors
grey_range <- colorRampPalette(c("#737373", "#F0F0F0"))

x <- seq(0,10,1)
y <- seq(11,20,1)
z <- seq(21,30,1)

# Then you set the range of grey colors
color_z <- grey_range(length(z))  

df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))

# Lastly you assign the colors to the factor Z
ggplot(df,aes(x,y, color=as.factor(z)))+
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values=setNames(color_z, levels(df$z))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

The very easy way is to do this

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y, color=as.factor(z)))+
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_grey()

# With the start = 0.2, end = 0.8 option you can regulate the intensity and direction of the grey
```

[image]

Comment: @LTD. Thank you very much for your comment and examples.

Comment: You are welcome ZT_Geo :) ! Hope they work for you. Please upvote or/and accept if it was helpful for you

Comment: you can remove the legend if you do not need it by adding 
``` 
ggplot() +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: you can also try the solution of Jonathan. Let me know if it works, I am happy to help